# Select one account when other accounts do not exist in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, conditional-statements, hiveql, where-clause

I want to select accounts when other account_type do not exist in Hive

I filter the records with  `Account_type = 'Second'`, but all records are coming

```
Select Account_ID, Account_type
From Account
Where Account_type = 'Second'
```

My expected result is :

```
Account_ID  Account_type

102         Second
```

The actual result is

```
Account_ID  Account_type

101         Second 
102         Second
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use analytic functions to calculate flag if some `account_type` exists for the `Account_ID`.

For example this analytic function

```
max(case when Account_type='First'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) first_exists_flag
```

will be `1` for all `account_id=101` records and `0` for all other records in your dataset. Hope you got the idea.

**Select Second account_type when First does not exist:**

```
with account as (
    select a.*, 
              max(case when Account_type='First'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) first_exists_flag,
              max(case when Account_type='Second' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) second_exists_flag
              --you can add more such flags
          from Account a
)

select account_id, account_type
  from account a
where a.account_type='Second' and first_exists_flag=0;
```

**Select Third account_type when First and Second do not exist:**

```
with account as (
    select a.*, 
              max(case when Account_type='First'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) first_exists_flag,
              max(case when Account_type='Second' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) second_exists_flag
              --you can add more such flags
          from Account a
)

select account_id, account_type
  from account a
where a.account_type='Third' and first_exists_flag=0 and second_exists_flag=0;
```

You can also calculate flag when some other than Third account_type exist:

```
max(case when Account_type <> 'Third'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) other_account_exist_flag
```

And filter using `other_account_exist_flag=0`

Comment: I have database as abc. I get the following error message when run this query.

ParseException line 1:13 mismatched input '.' expecting AS near 'ABC' in statement (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: with abc.account as (
    select a.*, 
              max(case when Account_type='First'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) first_exists_flag,
              max(case when Account_type='Second' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) second_exists_flag
              --you can add more such flags
          from abc.Account a
)

select account_id, account_type
  from abc.account a
where a.account_type='Second' and first_exists_flag=0;

Comment: with account as (
    select a.*, 
              max(case when Account_type='First'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) first_exists_flag,
              max(case when Account_type='Second' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account_id) second_exists_flag
              --you can add more such flags
          from abc.Account a
)

select account_id, account_type
  from account a
where a.account_type='Second' and first_exists_flag=0;